# Concat Multiple file and between file add file name

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hello I wanted to concat multiple file which are have same header, i have more than 100 files what i wanted is concat those file into single file
example: tab sep files

example mentioning two files here

CB341.count.txt

```
#id    exam1_count exam2_count total
roy123   20         25          45
jay245   30          0          30
rohan     0          0           0
```

CB341.count.txt

```
#id    exam1_count exam2_count total
roy123    15         35          45
jay245    35         30          65
rohan     20         30          50
aru        0         20          20
```

wanted combine this type of files as output looking line

```
#id    exam1_count exam2_count total
#CB341
roy123   20         25          45
jay245   30          0          30
rohan     0          0           0
#CB341
roy123    15         35          45
jay245    35         30          65
rohan     20         30          50
aru        0         20          20
```

can any one suggest me how can I achieve this output

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried already?

Comment: ` import glob
`read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")`
`with open("result.txt", "wb") as outfile:`
    `for f in read_files:`
  `      with open(f, "rb") as infile:`
 `           outfile.write(infile.read())`

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj i have tried above code

Comment: You do `outfile.write` for `result.txt` which is opened in `write` mode. Each each `write` overwrites the previous contents of the file. All you need is is to open `result.txt` in append mode as: `with open("result.txt", "ab") as outfile: ...`

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj, Okay can you show me some example code, i need to add those file name, I didnt know how to add

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's one way of doing it:

```
import glob

with open("result.txt", "ab") as outfile:
    read_files = glob.glob("*.txt")
    for f in read_files:
        with open(f, "rb") as infile:
            outfile.write("#"+os.path.basename(infile.name).split(".")[0]) # Write the file name.
            outfile.write(infile.read()) # Write the file contents.
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```
import os 
import glob 
outfile = open('results.txt','w') 
for files in glob.glob("*.txt"):
    b_name = os.path.basename(files)
    outfile.write(b_name+'\n')
    with open(files,'r') as infile:
         outfile.write(infile.read())
outfile.close()
```